# How can I get transparent window borders / titlebars in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, themes, transparency

There are plenty of GNOME Shell themes with transparent panels, and I might want a transparent window border / titlebar theme to go with it. The closest thing I can think of is Emerald, but that only works with Compiz AFAIK and GNOME Shell only works with Mutter.

Comment: 11.10 or 12.04?? LOOK at this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11453890

Comment: @BlueXrider That's for Unity's panel; it's definitely not what I'm looking for. I'm using 11.10 btw, but an answer that would be applicable to 12.04 as well would be nice.

Comment: Here is the theme you were looking for: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/MOD?content=166260&PHPSESSID=bac0f2155acef94771cfc8488965ea99

Answer (score 11):

Since the release of Ubuntu 12.10, `gconf-editor` has been officially replaced by `dconf-editor`. So the [answer by Ringtail](https://askubuntu.com/a/111026/112901) will not work.

**To enable Window Titlebar transparency in Ubuntu 12 onwards:**

1. Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Copy and Paste the following line:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and install the package.
4. Once installed, run **dconf-editor** in the terminal.
5. Navigate to **`org/compiz/gwd`**
6. Now change the values of the following to anything between 0 and 1:

   ```
   metacity-theme-active-opacity
   metacity-theme-inactive-opacity
   ```
7. Now you've changed the transparency of the Window Titlebars.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the other methods to work in Ubuntu 19.04 so I resorted to editing the gtk.css file:

```
nano ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

Here is the code I used:

```
/* add a 3-pixel border around windows */
decoration {
    border: 5px solid rgba(10, 10, 10, .3);
    background:rgba(10, 10, 10, .3);
}


/* customize the titlebar for active window */
.titlebar {
    background: rgba(10, 10, 10, .3);
    border-top:solid 1px rgba(10, 10, 10, .3);
    color:white; 
}


/* customize the titlebar for background windows */
.titlebar:backdrop  {
    background: rgba(10, 10, 10, .5);
    color:white;
}
```

Once the file is saved, run this command to apply your changes:

```
setsid gnome-shell --replace
```

See below for the final result.

[image: Gnome on Ubuntu 19.04 with windows that have transparent titlebars and borders]

Comment: Thank you, it works with most of the apps but not with some apps such as `nautilus`, `gedit`, etc.

Comment: I dont see a gtk.css file

Answer (score 1):

You can change the window border transparency using the gconf-editor. You can change the window transparency for all the window borders or for active window borders. To change the window borders transperancy you need to have the gconf-editor installed.

To install the gconf-editor open a terminal window (press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy+paste the following line:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

To start the gconf-editor press Alt+F2 and type: gconf-editor.

When the configuration editor is open click on apps -> gwd and change the value of the metacity_theme_active_opacity and the metacity_theme_opacity to a value lower then 1.0. To change a value all you have to do is double click on the name and change the value in the edit key window.

metacity_theme_active_opacity: changes transperancy for active window borders

metacity_theme_opacity: changes transperancy for all window borders

[source](http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/how-to-enable-transparent-window-borders-on-ubuntu-11-10/)

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work for me, even after logging out and doing a reboot. I think `gconf` is supposed to be deprecated in favor of `dconf`, anyway.

Comment: I will keep an eye out for a better way

Comment: The answer 1 works fine.

Comment: @Hanynowsky Mark as approved the answer that worked for you.

Comment: @GediminasJeremiahGudelis I already voted it up! The poster of this question is not me but WarriorIng64

Comment: So sorry ;) My bad...